# Horizontal tabbed menu in CSS, can't make active tab's border overlap inactive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an horizontal tabbed menu where every tab is the same width (given through CSS) and has a 3-sides border. Adjacent tabs' borders should collapse to a single pixel, but I haven't found a decent way to do this unless I use a negative 1px margin on one of the sides of each tab or turn everything into a `display:table-cell` and use `border-collapse: collapse`.

Either of those methods has a problem when it comes to the active tab display, since this element's borders should overlap its neighbors' ones on both sides.

Here's a small fiddle to show both cases: https://jsfiddle.net/0wet6rgr/1/

What's the best way to make this sort of menu?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the adjacent selector, `+` to select the `li` after the active one and change the color of the left border like so:

```
#test1 li.active + li {
    border-left: 1px solid #00FFFF; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n28k7v5c/)

Comment: This would break compatibility on older browser though, wouldn't it?

Comment: It's not supported <ie8 correct. Otherwise you're fine

Answer (score 1):

```css
#test1 li.active {
    border: 1px solid #00FFFF;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, position:relative is the new "float" when it comes to fixing stuff including z-index and the alikes.. this one works, thanks

Comment: It does break the submenu I was planning on using though, since it was based on the upper menu position, but I'll find a way around it

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wet6rgr/2/)

```
#test li {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

#test li.active {
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: I did mess around with z-indexes while I was trying another way, but they never worked properly... perhaps the position:relative property is what helps in this case?

Comment: for use z-index you need a position:relative yes, it work for me :p